# How to import decorator-wrapped function in Python?

Tags: python, function, warnings, decorator

I am trying to import a function from a Python file, but when I import it, the decorator is not imported with the function. How can I fix this problem?

```py
import functools
import warnings

def deprecated(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def deprecation_message(*args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn("Call to deprecated function %s." % func.__name__,
                      category=DeprecationWarning)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    deprecation_message.original = func
    return deprecation_message

@deprecated
def verb(string, verbose=1, thresh=1):
    if verbose >= thresh:
        print(string)
```

If, in another file, I run

```py
from python_file import verb

verb("Hello World")
```

I should get a warning message that says

```py
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function verb.
```

but this is not what happens.

On the other hand, if I copy and paste those two functions to a new file and then I run `verb("Hello World")` (that is, without importing them but defining them from scratch) the code works and the warning message is printed.

Comment: What is going wrong is that deprecation warnings are not shown by default. See the duplicate.

Comment: E.g. if I create a `python_file.py` module with the contents of your first code block then run `python -W all -c 'from python_file import verb; verb("Hello World")'` I see the warning.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works!